# unable to resize row widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, resize, agora.io

i just want to reduce my size of the layout ,if anyone could help:

```
return Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                MainAxisSize.max(){
                _expandedVideoRow([views[0]]);},
                MainAxisSize.min(){
                _expandedVideoRow([views[1]]);}
              ],
            ));
```

the size does not change.

Comment: I suggest formatting your code before posting your question. Also take a look at `Container` from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add width to the container like the below example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Width sizing"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: 70.0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 35.0,
                  height: 35.0,
                  color: Colors.blue),
                 Container(
                  width: 35.0,
                  height: 35.0,
                  color: Colors.green),
              ],
            ),),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Happy Coding!!!